# Python how to use multiprocessing pool in tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocess

How to use multiprocessing pool in tkinter app? How to avoid getting TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects

```
import tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing

class UI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.input = tk.Spinbox(self.root, command=self.calc)
        self.input.bind('<Return>', lambda event:self.calc(event))
        self.input.pack()

    def foo(self, x):
        return(x**2)

    def calc(self, event=None):
        print('---------- calc ----------')
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        pool.map(self.foo, [2])
        pool.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tt = UI()
    tt.root.mainloop()
```

The error message I get when self.calc() is triggered

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\William Yizhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Z:\Documents\workspace\PyTest\multiprocessing_tkinter.py", line 17, in calc
    pool.map(self.foo, [2])
  File "C:\Users\William Yizhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\William Yizhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\William Yizhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Users\William Yizhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\William Yizhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects
```

Comment: Extract `foo` outside of the class. Maybe it will work.

Comment: It does work if move foo() outside of the class UI. However, for an existing class and its member methods, is there any way to go around?

Comment: The problem is when you call `self.foo`, `self` is passed in as an parameter. And, `tk.Tk()` which is `self.root` in `self` cannot be pickled. That means you cannot transport it across processes. You can do whatever you want as long as you avoid implicitly transporting `tk.TK()`.

Comment: @Sraw, is there a way to avoid transporting tk objects? Thanks.